# html sanitization for user input in node

Tags: node.js

I'm doing this small side project to create a blogging app.

I'm taking the user input and save it to a file as it is which then is simply served.

Basically this is the flow:

```
[page]
    -> [User enters text] 
          -> [js transforms it to html] 
              -> [send back to server] 
                     -> [saved to file system] 
                           -> [served as it is]
```

I'm completely aware the solution as it is, is terrible and before reworking it I wonder if adding html sanitization in the server would be enough <strike>and if there's any library I should take a look at</strike>.

Comment: asking for iibrary recommendations is off topic for stack overflow. Have you tried searching on npm?

Comment: @gman you're right. Question updated to: Is that enough?

Comment: Seems now it's an opinion question which is also off topic? Is it enough? Joe thinks "yes", Jane thinks "no". Also, the question you've asked as a simple "yes" or "no" which doesn't seem very useful. Have you tried [searching for what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sanitize+%5Bnode.js%5D)